# Cause a script stored on a flash drive to execute when it is plugged into an OS X system

Tags: macos, autorun, usb-flash-drive, payload

I'm guessing this can't be done as it would be terrible security, can't even be done in windows 7, but is there a way to make a flash drive automatically preform a function when it is plugged into a mac with default settings. I assume all executable files are quarantined on the flash drive, but could it access environmental variable? Could the drives name contain a script? I'm just trying to think outside the box on this one, anyway, if anyone has any ideas I would love to hear them.

Thanks

November

Answer (score 2):

You can't. No form of autorun has been supported on Mac OS since around 1997, when [QuickTime 2.5 disabled CD autoplay by default](http://lowendmac.com/virus/worm.shtml).